# Setting up a development environment on SharePoint Online - O365

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, azure, intranet

We are in the process of developing Intranet on SharePoint Online for my organization. What are the options available to set up a development environment(On Prem or Azure)? So we dont have to make the changes on the production environment.

Any suggestions are helpful.
Thanks

Comment: @SMerchant. Thanks for your reply. If we have Azure instance available, Can we set up our dev site there, and use it as a developer environment?

Comment: What do you mean by Azure Instance? Do you have Sharepoint VM on Azure?

Comment: We don't right now. If we have Azure environment can we set up SharePoint VM on Azure. Is it recommendable?

Comment: If your intranet is on SharePoint online I won't recommend creating a VM on Azure.  It is much better to get a separate tenant for testing and find ways to replicate the environment